# Disable Qt mouse events when application does not have focus

Tags: windows, qt

I have a Qt (4.7) Windows 7 application in which certain components react to `QEvent::HoverEnter`, `QEvent::HoverLeave`, `QEvent::HoverMove`, `QEvent::MouseMove` events. When the main application window is displayed but does not have focus, I want to ignore these events.

For example, suppose that I have two windows side by side: my main application window, and a web browser window. If I click with the left mouse button on the browser window, the browser has the focus. If I now move the mouse pointer over my main application window without clicking on it, I do not want the application to react. The current behaviour is that my application receives mouse events and reacts to them (opens menus, and so on).

Since my main class `MyApplication` is derived from `QtSingleApplication`, I want to override the method

```
virtual bool MyApplication::notify(QObject* receiver, QEvent* event)
```

and add a test so that I can ignore specific events if my application does not have any window with focus. Is there a way to verify this condition in Qt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `QApplication::activeWindow()`, it will return zero-pointer if Your application is not in focus.